# SQL: Join tables using a value inside a JSON in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I'm using Grafana to access some PostgreSQL data (TimescaleDB). I have a 1st table called *events* that has one column called *event*, that is an object with this structure:

```
{"response_body": "{\"result\":[{\"profile\":{\"id\":123456}}]}"}
```

I also have a 2nd table called *orders* that has a column *profile_id* that corresponds to the **id** inside the object from the 1st table.

I want to join both tables (using the **id**) to access columns on the 1st table via the 2nd table, but I'm not sure how to make the INNER JOIN work:

```
SELECT
  event->>'url_path',
  SUM(size) AS "ORDERS SIZE (SUM)"
FROM
  events
INNER JOIN
  order ON order.profile_id = events.SOMETHING_HERE
GROUP BY
  1
LIMIT 10;
```

I've tried to use this on the SOMETHING_HERE part, but it doesn't work:

```
(event->>'response_body')::jsonb->'result'->0->'profile'->>'id'
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work just fine if you join on that (also swapping out multiple `->` for a single `#>>` and matching the types on both sides of `=`): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/kXIBV74s)

```sql
SELECT event->>'url_path' AS "URL PATH",
       SUM(size) AS "ORDERS SIZE (SUM)"
FROM events e INNER JOIN orders o ON 
o.profile_id = ((e.event->>'response_body')::jsonb #>>'{result,0,profile,id}')::bigint
GROUP BY 1
LIMIT 10;
```

| URL PATH | ORDERS SIZE (SUM) |
| --- | --- |
| example.com/exmpl | 70773 |

---

If you need more flexibility, you can look into [JSONPath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.21.1.1.1).

This checks all elements in the `result` array, not just the first one and it also returns the [value of a key](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH-OPERATORS) with "id" in it, regardless of whether it's surrounded by asterisks or not. In your query that would be:

```sql
SELECT event->>'url_path',
       SUM(size) AS "ORDERS SIZE (SUM)"
FROM events e INNER JOIN orders o ON 
jsonb_path_match ((event->>'response_body')::jsonb
                  ,'$.result[*].profile.keyvalue() 
                    ?(@.key like_regex ".*id.*")
                    .value == $order_profile_id'
                  ,jsonb_build_object('order_profile_id',o.profile_id::int) )
GROUP BY 1
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Zegarek! Interestingly, when trying your first approach (seems clearer to me), I get this error on Grafana: 
"db query error: porque: operator does not exist: bigint = text". 

And when I try the 2nd approach, I get this error: 
"CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner". What could be happening?

Comment: BTW, in my original code there were no asterisks, it was me trying to make the "id" bold in my message, sorry for that. But I've just removed the ** and ** for my code (1st approach), and it doesn't matter for the 2nd approach :) Let's see if you can help me figure out why I'm getting that error of "operator does not exist". Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to cast your `o.profile_id` to `text`, because both `->>` and `#>>` by design produce output of type `text` for your `id`. That, or you can also cast the resulting `id` to `bigint`. I assumed your `profile_id` was `text` because you chose to use a text-yielding operator from the start. As to the double asterisks, I had a sneaking suspicion that'd turn out to be the case.

Comment: Thanks @Zegarek. I've casted it to text indeed, it looks like this (right after the "INNER JOIN orders o ON" part): 
CAST(o.profile_id AS TEXT)= (e.event->>'response_body')::jsonb #>>'{result,0,profile,id}' however I get this error now: "CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner." Any ideas?

Comment: That CloudFront error doesn't seem to be directly related to the queries here. If the tables are massive, you might be hitting some low timeout setting, or there could be other limits in place, or you might just be facing some connection problems. All of these queries are tested and demonstrated on the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kXIBV74s) I linked as a demo.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Zegarek. Yeah, I'll see if it's a problem with the huge tables I'm trying to access to :/ Thanks for the support and for helping with the query anyways, you rock!